# Is it utf-8 suitable for text/plain mime type?

Tags: php, character-encoding, encode

I am exporting data through files. The output is base64 encoded data.

```
$data = base64_encode(serialize($data));
```

Which results in something like:

```
bGFzcyI6MTp7czo1OiJzZXR1cCI7YTo3Mzp7czoyNToicGFnZXNfY29udGFjdF91c19oZWFkbGlu
```

So I am wondering what charset is more suitable for this data (plain text). us-ascii seems enough but utf-8 always seems an error-proof default.

```
header('content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around the text/plain or utf8 parts of that.

Comment: @quentin Thanks. I really did not know it...

Comment: I still feel the accepted answer is wrong (even though mine got downvoted). I clarified my answer quite a bit, care to reconsider?

Comment: `utf8` as the charset is not valid, it's `utf-8`. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really doesn't matter; your content is valid `US-ASCII`, valid `UTF-8`, valid `ISO-8859-1` (or, I believe, *any* `ISO-8859-x`), valid `Windows-1252`, and so on. Just don't put `UTF-16` or `EBCDIC` or something.

(For what it's worth, I'd go with `US-ASCII`, because it's fully supported by even pre-Unicode computers without being so explicitly a pre-Unicode character-set as `ISO-8859-1` or whatnot; but that's really a subjective preference.)

Comment: Somewhere there is a spec that says you must state the charset as the smallest one that correctly describes it.  Thus if it is strictly ASCII, it must be called that instead of ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8, or if it the ISO-8859-1 subset of Windows-1252, you must say that, too. I think this is for email, so may not apply in this case, however.

Comment: @tchrist: You're 90% correct. The currently-relevant RFCs (2046 and 2616) do make that recommendation, but they use "should" rather than "must", which in RFCs is a meaningful distinction. Also, interestingly, RFC 2616 says that "not labeling the entity is preferred over labeling the entity with the labels US-ASCII or ISO-8859-1", but IMHO that's obsolete when it comes to ISO-8859-1, since many user agents now assume, in defiance of the standard, a default charset of UTF-8. (And I notice that IETF itself serves some pages with `charset=ISO-8859-1`.) But it may still apply to US-ASCII.

Comment: But even though it's compatible with US-ASCII, that does not make it US-ASCII :)  I clarified my own answer, do you still disagree?

Comment: @Evert: I never actually disagreed with your answer, and I don't know why anyone downvoted it; as a theoretical matter, this content isn't really "text". But as a practical matter, there may be benefits to pretending that it's text; for example, if the server serves it as text, then a browser will render it as text, which is useful for copying-and-pasting. And I'm guessing that the OP is taking advantage of these benefits, or else (s)he likely wouldn't feel the need to Base64-encode the data to begin with.

Answer (score 26):

You won't actually even need a charset. 'text/plain' may be incorrect though, because it's also not really text.

Even though it is compatible with ascii, utf-8, latin1 (as ruakh mentioned), you should just treat it as a binary file.

**Update**

I wanted to clarify this a bit (after all the downvotes, common guys give me a chance!)

@dan04: UTF-8 is text, I didn't say it wasn't. Base64 is not, base64 is also an encoding, but it can encode any binary sequence. Base64 is encoded in such a way that it possible to wrap it in US-ASCII (and therefore also UTF-8 and latin1 / ISO-8859).

Base64 is still just a binary sequence though, and not per definition text. The fact that the same range of octet-values are used as US-ASCII (and 'printable' by anything that reads US-ASCII) does not make it text.

This is also why Base64 does not have it's own mimetype. It's considered a content-transfer encoding. (look it up!)

So the actual correct way to serve Base64 it with the mimetype of what the string contains, along with a Content-Transfer-Encoding header. For example, if you're encoding a jpeg, this is the correct format.

```
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

This is also why I feel that if you don't want to say anything about the contents of the string (or don't have this information), it's best to treat it as 'generic binary', e.g.:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

Comment: +1 What you mention is really interesting. I'll have it in account in the future. In my case I used `US-ASCII` because indeed is a serialized object var. Thanks for your contribution.